# can't retrieve values from db in jhipster

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, junit, jhipster

I am new to Jhipster. I have created the project using "devDatabaseType":"h2Disk",
"prodDatabaseType": "mysql" as configurations.

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void getAllPlayersNS() throws Exception {
    int playersCount = playersNRepository.findAll().size();
    System.out.println(playersCount);
}
```

Here I am in the test file. When I executed the above code using 'gradlew test' it will print 0 as playersCount. So I believe playersNRepository methods are not working because there are values in the db. When I logged into h2-console, I can see the db values. So can I know where I get wrong?

Comment: As a result for that I have used playersNRepository option whch you mentioned. But it also not working.

Comment: findAll() was already generated in PlayersNServiceImpl.java. But I have doubt since it was returning List<PlayersNDTO>. I am not sure whether I need to implement findAll() method in playersNRepository also. Because playersNRepository interface is empty while extending JpaRepository<PlayersN, Long>. So yeah I assumed findAll()  was implemented in JpaRepository.

Comment: There can be a configuration issue. Config files are separate for test env which is located at /src/test/resources/. Make sure the yml file at this location has the correct db configuration.